# How to get the document id from a firestore document in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my App a user can have many different gymplans. So I have a collection where every gymplan has his own document. When creating a new plan I want to store the document id inside the document so that I have access to this document with the id.

When creating a new document firestore automatically create a unique id which is fine. But how can I get this id inside my code? So far my code to create a new plan looks like this:

```
  Future createPlan(String planName, List exerciseNames, List rows) async {
    return await usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).collection('plans').add({
      'planId': /// here i want to save the document id firestore creates
      'name': planName,
      'exerciseNames': exerciseNames,
      'rows': rows,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create the document first. Then use `set()` instead of `add()`. So:

```
final ref = usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).collection('plans').doc();
return await ref.set({
  'planId': ref.id,
  'name': planName,
  'exerciseNames': exerciseNames,
  'rows': rows,
});
```